# Public images only to Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase

I'm new to Google Cloud and Firebase. The website/apps are running client side in Vue. I am using Firebase for authentication/hosting/storage/functions. The problem is I want to have images in storage that are not publicly accessible but refer to them as if they were public. Aka put the assets in img src's and use it in places on the website.

It is expensive and slow to put every image through a function to check if authenticated. I would like to have /img/foobar.jpg which is really https://storage.*/img/foobar.jpg not run through a function but not be publicly accessible.

I can get an image to appear without a function if I upload an image and the owner is me (which is a Google account). That isn't going to work for everyone because the users of the site don't have Google accounts.

I was thinking I could make a bucket policy that says only direct links to the image won't work but the Firebase Hosting site can view the images publicly. Since the Firebase hosting site is behind a login, the assets would be protected. Is this possible? I don't see any documentation to back this.

Answer (score 0):

You state you are using firebase auth. In the rules of firebase storage, you can define that a file can be read only if the user is authenticated. Something like this would suffice:

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start for more information

Comment: I have done that but from mocking it up it appears the images would only he available via the sdk. It is a client side app so I would have to do a SDK lookup for every image and then inject it into the page. Right now I have it mocked that a Vue router accepts a path...there is some javascript to do a post to a function to return a signed url or token url and then I redirect. Not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Storage -> Rule

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```